# Where do the electrons in a lightning bolt come from?

Tags: electrostatics, electrons, atmospheric-science, lightning, weather

Where do the electrons in a lightning bolt come from?
There are problems with the explanations given up to at least two years ago.
The explanation that the electrons come from inside the thunder cloud or are derived from cosmic rays are inadequate.
There are a lot more electrons in a lightning bolt than those that come from these sources.
Is there research which shows were the electrons actually come from ?
Thanks.

Comment: You should link to the question(s) that contain the answers you are not happy with.  Don't expect people to go searching for it/them.

Comment: There are more electrons in a paper clip than there are in the typical lightning strike. It's getting them all to leave their atoms that's difficult.

Answer (score 0):

They dont need many in the beginning to start a snowball effect.In fact they are few then due to the snowball effect produced by bumping into air molecules they become many.